# How should I handle an object that has copies of another object?

Tags: object-oriented, python, database-design, django

I really hope this is a good place to ask this since the answers might be subjective, but here it my problem:

This is probably irrelevant, but I'm working with Python and Django here.

I have the Django `User` and each user is related to a `Company`. The user can create a company and save different copies of the Company after making changes to the details of the company. So my first thinking is to create a one-to-many relationship between `User` and `Company` Then every time the user makes change to the company and save, I can create a new object and save it under the user. This, however, feels like a bad design (scalability, for example). The deepcopy to save the copy under the user is also kinda ugly (I have to go through each related object and deepcopy them and reconstruct the Company object). One more problem with this approach is that I am going to have to modify the Django `User` to add a method like `getLatestCompany()` or something like that.

My alternative: create a proxy class (e.g. `Profile`) and have a 1-1 relationship with `User` then a 1-M between `Profile` and `Company`. I don't like this approach though, I would prefer if the relationship stayed between `User` and `Company`. Then my code can look like `user.getLatestCompany().MethodFromCompany()` instead of `user.profile.getLatestCompany().MethodFromCompany()`

Sorry for the long text, looking forward to getting some input :)

Comment: If a `User` has a one-to-many relationship with a `Company` then that implies a `Company` can only ever be associated with one `User`.     This seems odd to me.      Are you sure this shouldn't be a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: @BenCottrell that's right, but when I deepcopy a Company, I assign it a new PK and ID so the relationship stays one-to-many (since it's no longer the same company). I think a broader question here is: what is the best way to copy objects and keep track of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up serializing the copies (used Django Rest Framework), and saved it as a simple string under `Company`. Then I added a `deserialize()` method that reads the this field and re-constructs the object.